# Not able to scrape titles using bs4, python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the titles from the benefits tab from this link using the below code : https://www.yesbank.in/business-banking/cards/credit-cards/yes-first-business-card

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Hari\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.yesbank.in/business-banking/cards/credit-cards/yes-first-business-card")

d0 = []
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.title_contains('YES'))
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for x in soup_1.select('u strong , ul:nth-child(21) p > strong , ul:nth-child(19) strong , ul:nth-child(17) strong , ul:nth-child(7) strong , ul:nth-child(5) p > strong , ul:nth-child(10) strong , ul~ ul li+ li strong , ul:nth-child(13) strong , ul:nth-child(3) strong'):
    d0.append(x.get_text())

print(d0)

driver.quit()
```

But I am getting an error that is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\buffer.py", line 43, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  File "C:\Users\Hari\PycharmProjects\Card_Prj\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

My main aim is to print the 'd0' list

I have tried so many ways to resolve this issue but failed to do so.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by changing this:

```
EC.title_contains('YES'))
```

to this:

```
EC.title_contains('Yes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a try catch.

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains('YES'))
except:
    print('Not there')
```

Even better to deal with the exact error.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains('YES'))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(str(ex))
```

**Also YES is not equal to yes**